# How to get started in Card Games

Tags: c#

My end goal is to play a card game with my friends from other locations over the internet. I am going to start with a card game like blackjack and want people to be able to play in real time or close to it. I am not really sure where to start here and in which language. I was kind of thinking of making a website that can do this but I am not really sure. My end goal is to play MTG with friends and build decks.

Any ideas on a language to choose or where to get started? My current plan is C# asp.net webforms... Would Java be a good idea? I dont need it fancy, just functional. I am good at C and C# and some Java.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you need to know. Technology? Or are you asking about the architecture of such a game? As of now, this question is more like "How do I write a multiplayer card game" which is off topic according to the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirements, I'd suggest ASP or PHP for your game logic, a SQL database for your cards and so on, and DHTML/Ajax to breathe some life into the interface. This approach will be clean, stylish and responsive if implemented well. HTTP provides the reliable communication you need. Because card games are turn-based, the page-refresh paradigm can work very well even without DHTML, eg. [MArcomage](http://arcomage.netvor.sk/).

If you want 3D (cards), you could pull in WebGL to do that work for you.

Remember that if you want the game to be ostensibly secure from cheating, you need to implement the logic in backend, so don't use JS for your core game logic, only for the presentation. Clients cannot be trusted in regards to game state updates, only the server can. Clients should only send state delta's to the server, for it's intelligent approval and subsequent incorporation into the actual current game state.

The benefits of the ASP-or-PHP/HTML/CSS/JS approach over any compiled language, including something like Flash, is that the code-debug cycle is quicker -- "recompile" is a page refresh away.

On the other hand, if you're particularly familiar with doing all the necessaries in, say, Java, then by all means. But I guess if that were the case, you wouldn't be posting here ;)

Comment: In general, you make some good points (namely, how to prevent cheating), but I'd instead recommend using C# and asp.net, since the OP said he knows C# already.

Comment: I will be using asp.net to do this. I have already started and am on my way! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what languages you already know. but if I were to write a server I suggest you go with either asp.net or [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).